# Calling a stored procedure with null parameters and SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sqldataadapter

I have a stored procedure which I cann from my C# code. I am passing some parameters which I put in a HashTable first. It looks like that:

**paramname1    value1

paramname2    value2

paramname3    value3**

Any of the values can be **null**. So now I am going through that hash and add the params to the adapter:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in myHash)
{
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(entry.Key.ToString(), entry.Value);
}
```

This works, but when I try to fill a DataSet, it fails:

```
DataSet reportDataSet = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(reportDataSet);
```

The error message is that it complains about a missing procedure parameter. Ideas?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Please, describe stored procedure declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to check if its `null` and set it to `DBNull.Value` instead of `null` otherwise it thinks that the parameter is missing as it has a `null` value.