# error storing null date on repository

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

how can i put a null on repository combobox, where the data type was date time ?
or should i convert the date time to null ?
i try to put this code it give me error

```
public void store()
{

 GridView view = sender as GridView;
 for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {
 if (gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["signOut"] == DBNull.Value)
            {           
                DateTime? px = null;

                if (!repositoryItemComboBox10.Items.Contains(px))
                {
                    repositoryItemComboBox10.Items.Add(px);
                }
            }
}
}
```

[image error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L6eZ.png)

the error was `catch` on select query in other `method`

```
  public void SDB()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(command.CommandText, myConnection);
        try
        {
            ds2.Clear();
            dt2.Clear();
            command2.Connection = myConnection;
            command2.CommandText = " ..."
            adapter2.SelectCommand = command2;

            adapter2.Fill(ds2);
            adapter2.Fill(dt2);
            gridControl1.DataSource = dt2;

            myConnection.Open();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

conclusion what i want is to get filter, if the signout was blank or null
[image that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jinw4.png)

Comment: Can you post what the error message is? It could possibly have nothing to do with the repo object but rather that you're not catering for null SqlParameteres

Comment: eem, have you check the link image ? i dont know how to make it a thumb nail. yes, nothing to with the repository.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you cannot assign a null directly to a date. You can create a nullable date as follows

```
DateTime? px = (DateTime?)null;
```

Comment: Upon further investigation, I realize the error is on your command and not the repo item. Could you post a sample of your command text and how you're assigning parameters.

Comment: if i simplify it , it would be a regular syntax `SELECT signOut FROM time`
but the database of signOut some got null value. rather than convert a datetime to null so i think why dont i just called a null value type. and store it in reposiotry

Comment: One option is to use SqlParameters. Some like SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter(); param.AddWithValue("@MyParam", (object)MyParam ?? DBNull.Value); This is untested code ofcourse, but you can get the idea. MyParam would be your nullable parameter

Comment: mmh, is there any way like, how to convert date time if passing null value in date field ? rather than using sqlparameter .

Comment: Since you're using an SqlAdapter, you can have a look at -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254203/calling-a-stored-procedure-with-null-parameters-and-sqldataadapter . It shows how to assign parameters and adding them as nulls. It's Meant for a Stored Proc but you can change your code slightly to make it work  with inline sql

Comment: well, using this `if(!repositoryItemComboBox10.Items.Contains(DBNull.Value)){                       repositoryItemComboBox10.Items.Add(DBNull.Value);}` my repository item got null or blank value, but when i clicked it, i wont filter my column that has null value, knows why ?